# React Navigation Center Header Content and add Vertical Padding

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Using the follow packages and version:
react-navigation: 4,
react: 16.9.0,
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz,

I'm having trouble vertically centering the content in my header, as well as adding additional vertical padding in my header. My header looks similar to this:

[image]

You can see that with the simulator (iPhone X), there appears to be extra padding above the title. Similarly in the iPhone 8 simulator:

[image]

My code for the navigation currently looks like this:

```
const somePageStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  my_page: {
    screen: SomeComponent,
  },
  ...
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerLeft: () => (<View><Text>Left</Text></View>),
    headerRight: () => (<View><Text>Right</Text></View>),
    headerStyle: {
      // ... padding, margin, flex, etc. don't work
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headerstatusbarheight

Comment: @attila it already in center because above navigation bar there is 20 px status bar which is white and and not being visible that why it looks not center otherwise it is in center. This is my suggestion from your screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Try to set marginBottom in `headerTitleContainerStyle`

Here is sample code :

```js
createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {},
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerTitleStyle: {},
      headerTitleContainerStyle: {
        marginBottom: 10,
      },
    },
  },
}
```